# Spring boot, How to perform conditional query on many to many relationship with bridge table?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

**I have three entity include bridge entity:**

Team Entity:

```
       public class Team {
        
            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            @Column(name = "TEAM_ID")
            private Integer id;
        
            @Column(name = "teamname", length = 128, nullable = false, unique = true)
            private String teamname;
            @Column(name = "delete_date", length = 128, nullable = true)
            private Date delete_date;
        
            @Column(name = "description", nullable = true, length = 240)
            private String description;
        
            @Column(name = "active", length = 64, nullable = false)
            private int active;
            @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
            private Set<TeamUsers> team_users = new HashSet<TeamUsers>();

---getter setter constructur
    }
```

User Entity:

```
   @Entity
    @Table(name = "tblUsers")
    public class User {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Integer id;
        @Column(name = "Username", length = 128, nullable = false, unique = true)
        private String username;
        @Column(name = "FirstName", nullable = false, length = 45)
        private String firstName;
        @Column(name = "LastName", nullable = false, length = 45)
        private String lastName;
        @Column(name = "Password", length = 64, nullable = false)
        private String password;
        @Column(name = "Email", length = 128, nullable = false, unique = true)
        private String email;
        @Column(name = "Phone", length = 64, nullable = false, unique = true)
        private String phoneNumber;
    
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    
        private Set<TeamUsers> team_users = new HashSet<TeamUsers>();

---getter setter constructur

    }
```

TeamUsers - Bridge Entity with extra column(active):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "team_users")

public class TeamUsers implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TEAM_ID")
    private Team team;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "active")
    private Integer active;

---getter setter constructur
}
```

In the Team repository I have code:

```
package com.crmbackend.allService.teamService.repo;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;

import com.crmbackend.entity.Team;

public interface TeamRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Team, Integer> {

    @Query("select t from Team t")
    public List<Team> getAllTeamAndDetails();

}
```

If I call the getAllTeamAndDetails() method in Junit Test, the result is all team informations:
It basically tells me how many team I have, and team users object who belong to which team.

***Now, my question is which I want to get all team information and team user information,
but only their active = 1 in the bridge table.***

***which means if Team User record has active = 0, then this user should not showing in the result.***

How this query should be looks like or what is the best approach?

Thanks

Comment: Do you always want that (possible) or only in this query (not possible because there i no way to filter the collection in a query)

Comment: @SimonMartinelli if it is not possible, then is there are any other way? Finally I will have a API to return the team information and User information and giving to front end right. then what is the best approach here? do we need to fetch database multiple time to return to API layer?

Comment: Do you must use JPA? Because JPA does not support your use case. It will probably end with more than one query.  If you would use jOOQ for read you could do that in one query: https://blog.jooq.org/2021/07/06/jooq-3-15s-new-multiset-operator-will-change-how-you-think-about-sql/

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Yeah that is a good one I will give a check.
But I think my case is a very typical example with just only three tables. In the real world development, once the user go to Team management page, user will firstly see all the team information and users right? How those professioanl developer do to show all data back to UI using API calling on service layer?

Comment: These will be multiple requests. Not only one. You only load the data the user is currently seeing. So usually there is no tree loaded

Comment: Ok, so if I want to follow that way, then there are no need to using annonation OneToMany in the two eneity class and giving ManyToOne in the birdge entity class. 
I can simply create three individual entitis, and doing multiple API request. For example firstly I will get all team ID from Team Entity, then for loop Team ID get all bridge table data, then for loop again get all according users? feels not right.  how should I manage this?

Comment: Entities are for writing. For reading you better use DTOs or Interfaces. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with the plain JPA/Hibernate or Spring Data JPA tools available. You have to use a DTO for this purpose. I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Team.class)
public interface TeamDto {
    @IdMapping
    Integer getId();
    String getDescription();
    @Mapping("team_users[active = 1].user")
    Set<UserDto> getUsers();

    @EntityView(User.class)
    interface UserDto {
        @IdMapping
        Integer getId();
        String getUsername();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`TeamDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, TeamDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<TeamDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!